# SQLITE only unique correlation

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, sqlalchemy, unique, correlation

I would like to know, if there is a way to add only events to my SQLite Database when there is a unique correlation between two columns. I only want unique Connection-Events added.

Example between Source_IP and Dest_IP:

```
WRONG (Fist and Second Event are the same)

Source_IP     Dest_IP
1.1.1.1       2.2.2.2
1.1.1.1       2.2.2.2
1.1.1.1       2.2.2.3
1.1.1.2       2.2.2.2

RIGHT

Source_IP     Dest_IP
1.1.1.1       2.2.2.2
1.1.1.1       2.2.2.3
1.1.1.2       2.2.2.2
```

The same Source or Dest IPs can be added multiple times, but correlated only once. I am working with python (2.7) SQL-Alchemy.

My first thought was something like hash the src and dst IP to get one value, and put it into a column, I've set to UNIQUE.

Comment: Unique indexes can span multiple columns...

Comment: but how can i correlate them. so their values will be treated as "one" ? Or is this already done as soon I have multiple columns set as unique ?